# How to get the visible state of the Custom Control in SaveViewState override method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a custom dataBound control. I am lacking,

1. when the visible property of the custom dataBound control set as false in pageLoad means, in postback the control visibility not maintain.
2. I have override the saveViewState method, in that i have update the some of the properties of custom data bound control and stored that properties in object.
3. Same object , retried in LoadViewState method, i unable to get the visible property.

My requirements: I need to get the visible state of custom control in saveViewState method, but saveViewSate meth

```
protected override object SaveViewState(){

}
```

By, generally saveViewState method did not accept any arguments, then how come i get the visible state of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can able to get the default properties of custom controls in SaveViewSate method as follows

```
protected override object SaveViewState(){

    object[] myState = new object[2];
    myState[0] = base.SaveViewState(); // this will store the default properties status such as visible,
    return myState;
}


protected override void LoadViewState(object state)
{
    object[] myState = null;
    if (state != null)
    {
        myState = (object[])state;
    }
    base.LoadViewState(myState[0]);
}
```

In LoadViewState, you can able to restore the state as above.